# Error while accessing properties of object after GET request?

Tags: html, angular, typescript

I am using a weather api in my angular app and this is [an example response](https://gist.github.com/OussEmaDevCode/d1a8d22bd9e7c7d1e5af3ad898d23652) of the api.

I get my data via this function :

```
getTempByName(name) {
return this.http.get('https://api.weatherbit.io/v2.0/current?' + 'city=' + name + 
'&key=mykey');
}
```

and then assign it to an object via this code where weatherData is my Object :

```
weatherData: object;
this.fetch.getTempByName(this.name).subscribe(data => {
  if (data) {
    this.weatherData = data;
  } else {
    this.noty.notify('error', 'The city Name you entered is incorrect');
  }});
}
```

and then in my html I am using this code to show the data :

```
<div class="container" *ngIf="weatherData">
  <p class="country">{{weatherData.data[0].city_name}}</p>
  <p class="temp">{{weatherData.data[0].temp}}°</p>
</div>
```

Everything runs smoothly when I run the app on a local server but as soon as I build it via this command `ng build --prod` I have this error:

> ERROR in src/app/weahter-info/weahter-info.component.html(8,22): Property 'data' does not exist on 
>       type 'object'.
>       src/app/weahter-info/weahter-info.component.html(9,8): Property 'data' does not exist on type 
>       'object'.
>       src/app/weahter-info/weahter-info.component.html(10,31): Property 'data' does not exist on type 
>       'object'.
>       src/app/weahter-info/weahter-info.component.html(11,19): Property 'data' does not exist on type 
>       'object'.
>       src/app/weahter-info/weahter-info.component.html(14,73): Property 'data' does not exist on type 
>       'object'.
>       src/app/weahter-info/weahter-info.component.html(17,54): Property 'data' does not exist on type 
>       'object'.

I tried to find a way to ignore the error via various methods but I couldn't, any help will be welcome.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`weatherData: object;` change it to `weatherData: any;`

values come from API we want to opt-out of type checking and let the values pass through compile-time checks. To do so, we label these with the `any` type or you can create class or interface to avoid it